# grep regex .* not matching everything

Tags: command-line, grep, regex, unicode, utf-8

I've recently gotten into using tools like `grep`, `wc`, `cat`, etc. because I have to deal with some very large CSV files (>10GB) which aren't quite delimited correctly (for instance, having occurrences of the delimiter character *inside* some of the fields.

In my working with one of these files, I've run the following command in the process of trying to figure out a way to correctly identify which instances of `;` is a delimiter and replace them with some other character:

```
grep -v -n --text "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9].*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9].*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9].*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]" < Transactions.csv
```

The regex can probably be done much better, but anyway; what is surprising is that, among others, the above code outputs the following line:

```
12345678:2016-10-25;12345678912345;2016-10-25;gobbledegook �IDNR: 69 ;12345.67;.00;2003-09-05;12345678;2003-09-03;stuff stuff         ;12345 fgadfkjgbsdkb;12/3/45678/9
```

(as this was actually transaction data, I've changed most of the fields' values, except for the offending `�`) Maybe I'm being silly, but why doesn't the above regex match that line? It seems like the regex `.*` somehow doesn't match that character for some reason.

I suspect that the file is saved using the UTF-16 encoding, if that makes any difference.

**Edit:** Thanks to @exore for the answer. As it turns out, my file was encoded in ISO-8859-15, which I was able to figure by `grep`ping out the lines containing special characters, which were relatively few, into a file and opening that in gedit. I then used `iconv` to convert that to utf8, after which it worked fine!

Comment: Run `file` on it, it should tell you if the file is actually UTF-16.

Comment: @muru, I ran `file` on it but it says it's ASCII. From what I found on the Interwebs it seems that `file` only scans the first few lines of the file, so I guess that the offending characters appear much later in the file.

Comment: @LiamBaker BTW, from a quick look at some [PCRE docs](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/perl/regexp.html), I think you can make your regex easier to read by replacing things like `[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]` with `[0-9]{4}`, and `-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]` with `(-[0-9]{2}){2}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical char encoding problem. `.` means any character. But which sequence of byte is a legal character is a matter of encoding. Dealing with text without the knowledge of the encoding is a sure failure. Your grep command probably expect UTF-8 encoded string. UTF-8 is a multibyte encoding, meaning that some char are represented by multiple bytes. However, not all sequence of bytes are valid. See, for example, the [Wikipedia article on UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

When grep encounters a byte sequence that is not a valid char in the expected encoding, it cannot recognise it as a character, the line doesn't match, it's output. Since your terminal doesn't recognise the char either, you get a `�`.

There is a workaround in your case. Tell grep not to bother about encoding, and consider one byte as one char.

```
env LANG=C grep ....
```

or maybe

```
env LANG=C LC_ALL=C grep ....
```

You may test easily:

Create 2 files, one utf-8 encoded, one utf-16-be:

```
$ echo éléphant | tee file.std | iconv -f utf8 -t utf16be >file.utf16be
```

Check content of files:

```
$ cat file*
éléphant
�l�phant
```

Try to grep. The utf16be string is not recognised, no output:

```
$ grep '^.*$' file*
file.std:éléphant
```

Don't use encoding at all. One byte is one char. all strings are matched
the � just means the terminal doesn't recognise the utf16be sequence as a
valid utf-8 char. Note the use of `-a` to tell grep to consider binary is
is some text.

```
$ env LANG=C grep -a '^.*$' file*
file.std:éléphant
file.utf16be:�l�phant
```

Alternatively, if you know the encoding, then you can use `iconv` to first convert your file then use grep. One of the following should work.

```
iconv -f utf16   -t utf8 < file | grep ...
iconv -f utf16le -t utf8 < file | grep ...
iconv -f utf16be -t utf8 < file | grep ...
```